# How to get rid of weird numbers next to attached indicator on chart

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying to get rid of the numbers next to my strategy for a while and I can't seem to figure it out. It seems like they are populated for every line that is plotted on the chart. Not really sure what to do to fix it, even reading the pine script reference manual it did not help that much. Let me know if theres a potential fix for this thank you. I attached 2 pictures that highlight the issue. Again thank you all and I appreciate your time!

[Indicator with numbers thats kind of weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f379S.png)

[Additional Pictture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi1p7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.

I believe looking at my code that if there is an input that can be adjusted within the setting of the indicator (adjusted by the user setting button) all those inputs/price will appear as per your picture.

So for example if you had an EMA that you could adjust in the settings then the price that the EMA is at will appear as per your picture.

If you were to not have it as an adjustable input within the settings it should not appear.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Even so, the outputs are still going to be there